# Google map flickering on update current user location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using **Google maps** to draw path between start and destination location.
its working perfectly, when user travel, on update current location and draw route, using this delegate function.

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

   drawPath() 

}
```

Maps get flickering i am using this function to draw path

```
func drawPath()
{
   let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                let routes = json["routes"] as! NSArray
                self.googleMapView?.clear()

                    for route in routes
                    {
                        let routeOverviewPolyline:NSDictionary = (route as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSDictionary
                        let points = routeOverviewPolyline.object(forKey: "points")
                        let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points! as! String)
                        let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                        polyline.strokeWidth = 8
                        polyline.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2420450151, green: 0.487836957, blue: 0.9020499587, alpha: 1)
                        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
                        self.googleMapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 30.0))

                        polyline.map = self.googleMapView
                    }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
                self.addMarker(loc: desti)

            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

In other case without delegate functions travelled route polyline not clearing, but current location updating.

Can someone suggest a way, Thanks.

Comment: Try checking the same on real device.

Comment: Yes i am checking in real device and testing using gpx file.

Comment: @Leela display screenshot

Comment: Yes i added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to draw route just once either in viewdidload and just update the marker position on location change. So this would remove the route drawing flicker and just move the market on position change.

Comment: yes.. i followed your suggestion that issue got fixed..thanks.